# Add onclick attribute using jquery for IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

Add `onclick` attribute using jquery that should work in for IE7. I have used

```
idlink=Removelst();
var newclick = new Function(idLink);

$(test1).attr('onclick', null).click(newclick);
```

It works only in >IE8 and mozilla browser.

Comment: Not enough detail. What is $(test1) ? - where's the relevant HTML fragment?

Comment: i dont understand why you need to do so much instead you can add jquery click event handler since you are already using jquery.

Comment: var test1 = "#WrapAddBtn a";                             idlink=Removelst();
var newclick = new Function(idLink);
$(test1).attr('onclick', null).click(newclick);
I need the code that should work in IE7 also. Can u help? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
idlink=Removelst; // no () after function name
var newclick = new Function(idLink);
$(test1).click(newclick);
```

**Reason:**

The statement `idlink=Removelst();` does not set a handle to the function in `idlink`, rather it executes the function and stores its result in `idlink`

Answer (score 0):

either add an onclick function with

```
$(test1).attr('onclick', newclick)
```

or add a click event (which is a lot nicer)

```
$(test1).click(newclick)
```

Comment: I need the code that will work in IE7 also. I have tried this but but failed.